# Why does Code Review not accept the 'improve' keyword in question titles?

Tags: discussion, questions, quality-filter

I can understand the problem with asking questions on Stack Overflow that start with `'...how to improve...'` but Code Review does not let me add the word "improve", which I think is a bit hmm... awkward.

The whole point of the review is to improve the code, so... just thinking if there is another reason for this?

Comment: Why didn't you ask this at Meta Code Review?

Comment: [Meta Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com) is for discussion of Code Review. All Stack Exchange sites have their own Meta.

Comment: It's been this way for years.

Answer (score 3):

From [Code Review Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):

> ### Titling your question
>
> State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about
> it. Be descriptive and interesting, and you'll attract more views to
> your question.
>
> Here are some examples of titles that are unacceptable because they
> are too generic:
>
> - *How can I make this faster?* (Everyone prefers faster code. The
>   performance tag can convey this desire.)
> - *Simplify this chain of if
>   statements* (Applies to too many questions.)
> - *Ruby function needs
>   refactoring* (Reviewers will decide if it needs refactoring. You don't
>   have to ask for it in the title.)
> - *Is this good OOP design?* (Title is
>   not distinctive.)
> - *Online judge says Time Limit Exceeded* (Title tells
>   us nothing beyond what would be conveyed by programming-challenge and
>   time-limit-exceeded tags.)

**Your title should state what the code *does*, not what you want help with,** therefore you should not use `how to improve`.

Comment: @samaYo you're missing the point - help and improvement is a given when people review at CR - you do not need to say that in the title. If you want, say it in the body, **but not in the title**.